# Is it possible to index a document property and add it as a column in a SQL view?

Tags: marklogic

We are replicating some data from a relational database to marklogic and would like to verify if the  data is replicated properly. We wanted to create a view to compare the data.

Unfortunately, we don't store the last updated timestamp element in the document, but it is available as a document property. Is there a way to index the properties of documents and add that as a column for a view?

Answer (score 1):

This might be too disruptive, but you could create a script to update the documents to copy the property timestamp to an element or attribute value and - depending on how many documents need updating - run it in batches on the Task Server using `xdmp:spawn()`.

Answer (score 1):

Got this answer from Marklogic support.

*Unfortunately, views do not provide the ability join the document and property fragments. So it is not possible to add document properties as a column to the view.*

Answer (score 0):

Properties are elements, so you can create a range index on `prop:last-modified` just like any other element. And you could include it in a view.

However it's not clear from the docs whether that will actually work in a SQL view, and my experiment was unsuccessful. You might try asking MarkLogic support to get a definitive answer, and file an RFE if the answer is no.

Comment: Yeah. I tried that, but it didn't work. I'm just wondering how the document properties are tied to a document in a ODBC setup in Marklogic. I agree the documentation on odbc is not very comprehensive and I don't know the internals of how it works. I am going to raise a support ticket for this. Thanks for your reply.